# BroadcastReceiver's onReceive not called when battery level changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have BroadcastReceiver with BATTERY_CHANGED IntentFilter. When I try send broadcast, onReceive doesn't call. What's wrong? Here is my receiver description in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.BatteryReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My BroadcastReceiver

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("tag", "onRecv");
    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    if (level != -1 && scale != -1) {
        float batteryPct = level / (float) scale;
        if (batteryPct < 30) {
            NotificationBuilder.notifyWithActions(context, R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp,
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.battery),
                    context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.battery));
        }
    }
}`}
```

I try

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Comment: are you calling it locally? triggering the intent?

Comment: afaik; it wont work, you can trigger systems intents..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying this one of broadcast for battery level detect and it doesnt work.
Then for this task i use to create broadcast in MainActivity and register it with action Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED and there is no need to register receiver in manifest.xml and it works better.

Here whenever Battery level changed then the Broadcast call and task in block of onReceive(Context c, Intent i) is executed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private BroadcastReceiver BatteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

        // Getting level of Battery   
        int level = i.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Battery Level:" +Integer.toString(level) + "%",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // For any Level you have to check here.
        if (level == 100) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Battery Full",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Register receiver with Action and no need to define Broadcast in manifest.xml
    registerReceiver(BatteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the fake system broadcast via adb:

```
adb shell am broadcast "intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED;i.status=5;i.voltage=4155;i.level=100;end"
```